# Discord bot look for reactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So its hard to explain my situation because i am new to discord.js and i have been trying to figure this out for hours

What i need is my bot to look at a certain channel and see that a staff member (or anyone because normal users cannot add reactions) reacted with "" and logs it.

Later my end goal is it sees this and replys and sends a command to a minecraft server. but ill figure all that out later. i just need the bot to see that there is that certain reaction on a message

Like i said i am new, and the docs to discord.js are not helping, all i could find/do is this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === Discord.Message.author.id;
};

const collector = Discord.Message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});
```

And it throws errors about the Message.createReactionCollector

Comment: Welcome, SO is not a free code writing service. Have you tried anything? If so, add that code to your question.

Comment: added image. im not asking someone to write my code but i really dont undersand how this works, im new to discord.js. more used to creating plugins for other games

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of code. You can read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) why. Include your code inside of a code block, see  [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Also it is throwing that error because `.createReactionCollector()` is an instance method. Meaning that you need to call it on an instance of `Message`.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `ReactionCollector` you will need an instance of `Message` to create the collector on.

If you don't have a specific message and want to collect the reactions globally, you could listen for an event `messageReactionAdd`.

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

    // Ignore the bot's reactions
    if (client.user.id == user.id) return;

    // Look only for thumbs up reaction
    if (reaction.emoji.name != "") return;

    // Accept reactions only from specific channel
    if (reaction.message.channel.id != "870115890367176724") return;

    console.log(`${user.tag} reacted with .`);

});
```

Note that this won't work for reactions cast on messages sent before the bot was started. The solution is to enable [Partial Structures](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html). *(If you are dealing with partial data, don't forget to **fetch**)*